# How can I ensure the keyboard in a native view of a flutter plugin gets dismissed?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, plugins, keyboard, native

The keyboard in the native view is dismissed on swipe down, but when returning to the Flutter application, the view is cut off where the native keyboard was.  Is there a way to ensure its dismissed properly?  Is this even the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out with this in the native iOS code.

```
 @objc func dismiss() {
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.endEditing(true)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one?

```
Future.microtask(() => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()));
```

If not, then try this out:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: ...
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, this I understand but will it assist with the native keyboard at all? As this is dart code, not swift. 

More background, I have a plugin that utilizes a third party SDK, the keyboard comes from the swift section of the plugin.